# token request with Oauth 2.0 failing

Tags: php, http, oauth-2.0, hotmail

I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 authentication to Hotmail (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx#authcodegrant for details) in the beta version of my website. I checked many times my code and everything seems correct. Anyhow when I request the access token with

```
file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I get false as a result. Printing

```
$http_response_header
```

this is the answer I get:

```
array(10) { 
[0] => string(24) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" 
[1] => string(23) "Cache-Control: no-store" 
[2] => string(16) "Pragma: no-cache" 
[3] => string(19) "Content-Length: 115" 
[4] => string(30) "Content-Type: application/json" 
[5] => string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5" 
[6] => string(24) "X-WLID-Error: 0x80049D66" 
[7] => string(40) "PPServer: PPV: 30 H: BAYIDSLGN3C054 V: 0" 
[8] => string(35) "Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 16:44:40 GMT" 
[9] => string(17) "Connection: close" }
```

Can anyboby point me in the right direction to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the beta version... in the online version it works! Problem solved!